# How can I tell if this parametric equation intersects?

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric

How can I tell if this parametric equation intersects?

[image]

Each of them $(X_1=X_2, Y_1=Y_2, Z_1=Z_2)$ are equal to $0$. Does this mean they do not intersect? Are they parallel?

I am willing to clear things up need it be, of if there's any information currently missing that you'd like to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. This site uses MathJax to typeset mathematical expressions. Questions submitted as images cannot be searched or indexed. Here is a [brief tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset your question.

Comment: Thank you. Will keep in mind and make a new post then

Comment: What exactly have you posted? What is the math going on? If you did it, you should know what $0=0$ means.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, they will intersect. Actually, your starting point is correct, but you need to define your problem in a mathematical way.

In brief, if there exists a pair $(t,u)$ that makes $x(t)=x(u)$ and the same for $y,z$, then you can claim they intersect. Otherwise, they don't. To be more specific, if there is a solution for
\begin{align}
t+5&=4u+11\\
2t-6&=-2u-4\\
3t-1&=6u+11,
\end{align}
then these two lines intersect. The solution can be easily obtained as $(t,u)=(2,-1)$. So there is an intersection.

To check if two lines are parallel, you can wrap it up as another math problem that if $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=|\frac{d}{du}x(u)|$ and the same for $y,z$. If the answer is yes, then these two lines are parallel.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was a bit lost on how to continue. This is very helpful.

Comment: If you think this answer is helpful, please accept and upvote this answer, which can be helpful to others who have a similar question.